# How can I easily align an element with "display: inline-block" and "overflow: hidden"?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, baseline

`inline-block` elements using `overflow: hidden` position themselves so their bottom margin is the baseline. From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its
>       last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no
>       in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a
>       computed value other than 'visible', in which case the
>       baseline is the bottom margin edge.

In practice this means these elements are shifted up unexpectedly; e.g., inside a `<td>` the element will not be vertically centered. A simpler example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}
.h {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ib">Visible</div>ABgjh</div><br>
<div>
  <div class="ib h">Hidden</div>ABgjh</div>
```

the `div` with `overflow: hidden` doesn't share the same baseline as its surrounding line.

I'm looking for a simple way to make that `div` align itself as if it was following the normal rules for `inline-block` elements. Basically I want to write a custom element that "just works" whether its consumer applies a `vertical-align` style, or places it inside a `<td>`, etc.

[This table has an example](http://jsfiddle.net/5g2ejzww/1/) where I want the element to vertically center itself but instead it pushes itself up (and the rest of the line down).

[This fiddle has more examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxofxgpt/) showing how different pairings of vertical-align behave unexpectedly when one element is `display: inline-block; overflow: hidden`.

To be clear, this question is asking whether a `<div style="overflow: hidden">` can be wrapped in such a way that it can be treated as a regular `inline-block` element, positioning itself intelligently, without JS or font-based pixel adjustments. I'd want to be able to apply styling to the final component in order to position or align it as I please, as if it were a regular `inline-block` element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what browsers you are looking to support but if you wrap your `DIV` with `display: flex;` you wont get that vertical offset. You can see it here:

```css
    div {
      border: 1px solid red;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .ib {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .h {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .flex {
      display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ib">Visible</div>
  ABgjh
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="ib h">Hidden</div>
  ABgjh
</div>
```

I normally don't use flexbox because of the lack of browser support but perhaps this is the simple solution you're looking for. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd still like the div to behave as inline-block; wrapping with flex (or inline-flex) causes different behavior. Try, for example, inserting a `<br>` within the "ABgjh" text.

FWIW, I'm only using this for Chrome UI, so a Chrome-specific solution is fine.